# How to perform LEFT JOIN with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to perform something like this

```
SELECT  g.Name, g.emailID, g.phoneNo
FROM roomAllocation as ra
// if ra.guest_email is NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN Guests as g ON ra.guest_email = g.emailid
// else
LEFT JOIN Guests as g ON ra.guestPhoneNo = g.PhoneNo
```

Comment: This really makes no sense.  Your code snipper references 3 tables.  More explanation and a more complete query would help.

Comment: sorry about that, I've edited it with the complete query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to conditionally join to a table.  I would recommend two `left join`s as in:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(ge.name, gp.name) as name
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 ge
     on t1.guest_email = ge.email_id left join
     table2 gp
     on t1.guest_phoneNo = gp.phoneNo and t1.guest_email is null;
```

Because it is the same table, you could also use `or` in the `on` clause:

```
select t1.*, g.*
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 g
     on t1.guest_email = geemail_id or
        (t1.guest_phoneNo = g.phoneNo and t1.guest_email is null);
```

However, `or` in an `on` clause usually kills performance.

Answer (score 2):

Formally

```
LEFT JOIN Guests as g
     ON CASE WHEN table1.guest_email NOT NULL
             THEN table1.guest_email = table2.email_id
             ELSE table1.guest_phoneNo = table2.phoneNo
             END
```

But this kills indices usage. I'd recommend [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64153917/10138734).

Answer (score 1):

Guess you could split it up into 2 queries with a UNION:

```
SELECT  g.Name, g.emailID, g.phoneNo   
FROM roomAllocation as ra 
LEFT JOIN Guests as g ON ra.guest_email = g.email_id  
UNION  
SELECT  g.Name, g.emailID, g.phoneNo   
FROM roomAllocation as ra 
LEFT JOIN Guests as g ON ra.guest_phoneNo = g.phoneNo
```

Using UNION will merge the two results if they are overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work

```
 LEFT JOIN Guests as g
 ON (case when RA.guest_email IS NOT NULL 
 then RA.guest_email else RA.guest_phoneNo end) = (case when RA.guest_email IS NOT NULL then g.email_id else g.phoneNo end)
```